# Geoserver wms reflect zoom level

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms

I am trying to get a Geoserver wms request using reflect option as static layer to embed into a webpage through a url like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/container/wms/reflect?REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&VERSION=1.1.0&WIDTH=700&HEIGHT=550&SERVICE=WMS&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=layer1&BBOX=Long1,Lat1,Long2,Lat2&SRS=EPSG:4326
```

,my question is about the zoom level of this layer.
Could be possible to apply a zoom level into this url request?.I would like to apply a zoom level 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could be possible to apply a zoom level into this url request?

No.

The concept of "zoom level" can only apply for grid-based reference systems (e.g. [TMS](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification)).

For WMS, you are providing both the bounding box of the area you want and the width-height of the image you want. The "zoom level" is implicit, defined by the ratio between those two parameters.